# Print values from both files using awk as vlookup

Tags: bash, dataframe, awk, vlookup

I have two files, file1:

```
1 I0626_all 0 0 1 1 
2 I0627_all 0 0 2 1 
3 I1137_all_published 0 0 1 1 
4 I1859_all 0 0 2 1 
5 I2497_all 0 0 2 1 
6 I2731_all 0 0 1 1 
7 I4451_all 0 0 1 1 
8 I0626 0 0 1 1 
9 I0627 0 0 2 1 
10 I0944 0 0 2 1
```

and file 2:

```
I0626_all 1 138
I0627_all 1 139
I1137_all_published 1 364
I4089 1 365
AfontovaGora2.SG 1 377
AfontovaGora3_d 1 378
```

At the end I want

```
1 I0626_all 138 
2 I0627_all 139
3 I1137_all_published 364
```

I tried using:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b[$3]} {print $1,$2,b[$3]}' file2 file1
```

But It doesnt work.

Comment: You never use the `a` array for anything. And you're not putting anything into `b[$3]`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how the result is related to the input files?

Comment: Do you have to use `awk`? I think you could use the `join` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {map[$1] = $NF; next} $2 in map {print $1, $2, map[$2]}' file2 file1

1 I0626_all 138
2 I0627_all 139
3 I1137_all_published 364
```